# GWT - Get session object

Tags: java, session, gwt

I have one attribute in session (set while authentication completed). Now I want to send the same attribute in my requests which is getting build with:

`RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, queryUrl);`

how can I get the session object in my `GWT` code and get attribute from it. So I can send the same with the request.

I tried searching it but could not find appropriate solution. Can anyone help me?

Edited: This is for security. Once user is logged in, I'll generate a random token and set it into the session object now I want to pass this token into every request which is build through `RequestBuilder` so I can validate tokenPerRequest with tokenPerSession. So how can I pass that token.?

Thanks.

Comment: Session object only exist within the Servlet context, at the server side. If you need attributes available within the client request, use a Cookie. What is your use case? The same session object is available within the Servlet Request/Response. If you logged in, you can get using the getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(). It should have the attribute there.

Comment: @André I have edited my question to add scenario.

Comment: Note that GWT contains some anti-XSRF measures of itself that look a lot like what you're trying to do. See http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideSecurityRpcXsrf.html